# Error trying to establish bluetooth connection from android device C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to connect my android device to another device over bluetooth using rfcomm.
I am working in C#/xamarin.
Here is my code....

```
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;

        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        if(btAdapter != null && btAdapter.IsEnabled)
        {
            btDevice = (from bd in btAdapter.BondedDevices
                                        where bd.Name == "NAME"
                                        select bd).FirstOrDefault();
            if (btDevice != null)
            {
                UUID uuid = UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 10) // Gingerbread 2.3.3 2.3.4
                    AndroidBluetoothSocket = btDevice.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                else
                    AndroidBluetoothSocket = btDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                AndroidBluetoothSocket.Connect();
            }
        }
```

on the last line where Connect() is called, it throws the following error:

Java.IO.IOException: 'read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1'

The android device is already paired with the other device.  I have tried with retrieving the UUID on my own, but it also returns that same value.  I have tried the Create function with both Insecure and not.  I also have all of the bluetooth permissions selected in the AndroidManifest.xml.  I know it can find the device because my AndroidBluetoothSocket object is getting set correctly.

You will notice my solution works like many others you can find out there.  I found a couple that reference trying to use a Java function when this fails.  Unfortunately that doesnt work as i am using c#.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Android is already connected to another device and not allowing your new connection.

Comment: could you elaborate? i dont have any other devices connected.  And when i breakpoint after the Create, i can see that it did grab my device.

Comment: The error says : "The android device is already paired with the other device".  could you be connecting twice?

Comment: turns out it was an issue with the device i was connecting to.  The code above was exactly what I needed.